# How can I combine lists while preserving order within certain groupings?

Tags: python, finance

I am trying combine multiple years of income statments. However, the line items for each income statement vary from year to year. For instance, the 2020 income statement might include:

Revenue from Sales
Revenue from Services
Cost of goods sold
Total Gross Profit
Insurance
Payroll
Total Operating Income
Taxes
Net Income

While the 2021 income statement might include:

Revenue from Sales
Revenue from Consulting
Cost of goods sold
Total Gross Profit
Insurance
Maintaince
Payroll
Total Operating Income
Taxes
Interest
Total Net Income

I want to combine these lists so that the everything that falls above total gross profit will be grouped together, everything that falls between gross profit and operating income grouped together, etc. The individual items must correspond to their total line item. Is there a way to do this in python without loosing the order?

Thanks!

I can concatinate and remove duplicates, but I can't get it to maintain the order.

Comment: Can you specify how your lists are structured in a better way, maybe inserting the list in the question? If you don't want to lose the order information you should iterate over both of them and update the content at each step.

Comment: Please create an example for us to try, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)